# Pass parameter to module function Node.js

Tags: node.js

New to Node.js, and Im wondering if it's possible to pass a parameter to a module function? Something similar to this:

module.js:

```
module.exports = {
  example1: function(parameter) {
    return "hello, world";
  },

  example2: function(parameter) {
    return "hello,world";
  }
};
```

Then call it like so...

```
var mod = require("./module.js")
mod.example1(passedParameter);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. But you might have been quicker just trying that out than posting a question and waiting for someone to answer. ;)

Comment: @BadIdeaException For some reason when I tried what I listed above it crashed :/ Wasn't trying to be lazy! haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function attached as an exported property as shown in your answer is just a function like any other function.  You decide what arguments you want it to accept and process and what arguments to pass it.  It's just like any other Javascript function definition - you decide how to define and use it.  The fact that it's an exported property from a module does not make any difference.  It's just a Javascript function like any other.  It happens to live in a particular module, but other than that, you can do anything with it that you can with any other function definition.

> I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a parameter to a module
>   function?

Yes, it is possible and is common.